# similarity method for italian language in spacy not working

Tags: nlp, spacy

how can I get the similarity method of spacy for the Italian language?

**Italian Code:**

```
import it_core_news_lg
nlp = it_core_news_lg.load()

doc1 = nlp("vuole AUX aux")
doc2 = nlp("Apple PROPN ROOT")

# Similarity of two documents
print(doc1, "<->", doc2, doc1.similarity(doc2))
```

**return --->**

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-db17c0966749> in <module>()
      1 import it_core_news_lg
----> 2 nlp = it_core_news_lg.load()
      3 
      4 doc1 = nlp("vuole AUX aux")
      5 doc2 = nlp("Apple PROPN ROOT")

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/spacy/language.py in create_pipe(self, name, config)
    298         return SimpleFrozenList(
    299             self._components, error=Errors.E926.format(attr="components")
--> 300         )
    301 
    302     @property

KeyError: "[E002] Can't find factory for 'tok2vec'. This usually happens when spaCy calls `nlp.create_pipe` with a component name that's not built in - for example, when constructing the pipeline from a model's meta.json. If you're using a custom component, you can write to `Language.factories['tok2vec']` or remove it from the model meta and add it via `nlp.add_pipe` instead."
```

**English Code:**

```
import spacy
import en_core_web_lg
nlp = en_core_web_lg.load()
doc1 = nlp("I like salty fries and hamburgers.")
doc2 = nlp("Fast food tastes very good.")

# Similarity of two documents
print(doc1, "<->", doc2, doc1.similarity(doc2))
```

**Returns--->**

```
I like salty fries and hamburgers. <-> Fast food tastes very good. 0.7687607012190486
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the way you load the model.. what version of spaCy do you use? Did you try `import spacy; nlp = spacy.load('it_core_news_lg')`?

Comment: spaCy version    3.1.1

Comment: yes, tried import spacy; nlp = spacy.load('it_core_news_lg') but this method is not working for me...  OSError: [E049] Can't find spaCy data directory: 'None'. Check your installation and permissions, or use spacy.util.set_data_path to customise the location if necessary.

Comment: Ok I just tried a few things on [kaggle](https://www.kaggle.com/) and initially I got the same `data directory: 'None'` error, but when I opened a fresh notebook, ran `!pip install -U spacy && python -m spacy download it_core_news_lg`, it worked fine (both `import model_name` and `import spacy; load('model_name')`). Maybe try a fresh install or downgrade to an earlier version of spaCy if that's possible?

Comment: You can have a look at the kaggle notebook [here](https://www.kaggle.com/fabiansimonjetz/notebookc7e6e5d626/edit).

Comment: Sorry, this is the first time I shared a notebook – it should be all set now.

Comment: Your initial Italian code does not give me an error, it just works. What is the output of `spacy info`? I suspect you have a mix of model and spaCy versions. Also I recommend you load the model with `spacy.load("it_core_news_lg")` and your example sentences in Italian look weird.